# python mock: replacing a class method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Consider the following code (not a very good design, but that's the point):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,filepath):
        self._access_file_system(filepath)

    def get(self):
        return self._result_dict


class B(object):
    def __init__(self,filepath1,filepath2):
        self._filepath1 = filepath1
        self._filepath2 = filepath2

    def foo(self):
        a1 = A(self._filepath1).get()
        a2 = A(self._filepath2).get()
        return a1['result']==a2['result']
```

Now, if I want to test `B.foo()`, I need to mock `A` (as it accesses the file-system inside the constructor).

To write a test that will make sure `B.foo()` returns `False` in case `a1.get()` and `a2.get()` provide different values, I also need to mock `B.get()`.

So, the test function should probably look like the following:

```
import mock
mock_get = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=[{'result': 0}, {'result': 1}])

@mock.patch('__main__.A')
def test_foo(MockA):

    b = B('/file1','/file2')
    res = b.foo()
    assert res
    MockA.assert_any_call('/file1')
    MockA.assert_any_call('/file2')

    #Doesn't work -
    #the assignment doesn't propagate into the objects instantiated inside foo()
    #A.get = mock_get

    #The assigned method propagates into the class definition,
    #so it works - BUT WHY?!
    a = A(None)
    a.get = mock_get

    b = B('/file1', '/file2')
    res = b.foo()
    assert not res
```

Now, the strange point - as may be seen from the comments inside the code, if we assign `mock_get` to the class, it won't propagate, but if we create an instance and assign to it, it propagates to other instances of the class.

I suppose this behavior is related to internal mechanisms of `mock`, so it's important for me to understand it, to make proper usage of this library with all it's rich functionality.

So, does anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first case I can not see anywhere that you are patching the `get` method. You should assign the mock value to the `get` method of `A` before `B` is called. For instance why does the following test fail?:

```
import mock
mock_get = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=[{'result': 0}, {'result': 1}])

@mock.patch('__main__.A')
def test_foo(MockA):

    MockA.get = mock_get

    b = B('/file1','/file2')
    res = b.foo()
    assert not res
    MockA.assert_any_call('/file1')
    MockA.assert_any_call('/file2')
```

The reason for the previous behaviour is that we are forgetting to patch the return value of the object (A), in this case `MockA`, instead of the object itself (`MockA`). The `A` object is the result of instantiating the `A` class and you should access the method throgh the `return_value` of the `A` class. In your example it would be something similar to this:

```
import mock
mock_get = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=[{'result': 0}, {'result': 1}])

@mock.patch('__main__.A')
def test_foo(MockA):

    MockA.return_value.get = mock_get
    b = B('/file1','/file2')
    res = b.foo()

    assert res
    MockA.assert_any_call('/file1')
    MockA.assert_any_call('/file2')
```

You can check some of the following posts for more info on common python unit testing pitfalls:

- https://esaezgil.com/post/unittesting_pitfalls/ (written by me)
- http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/
- And of course the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html